# How to configure kafka to reclaim disk spacke when it exceeds log.retention.bytes?

Tags: apache-kafka, diskspace

I set `log.retention.bytes=1073741824`, `retention.bytes=1073741824`, `partitions=3` and `log.cleanup.policy=delete` but disk usage grew up to 13gb now.

Can I configure kafka to reclaim disk space?

Answer (score 0):

`log.retention.bytes` is per each topic-partition, although I feel the current documentation looks quite confusing.

Description of old Kafka documentation 0.8.2 looks much clear. (https://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html)

> The amount of data to retain in the log for each topic-partitions. Note that this is the limit per-partition so multiply by the number of partitions to get the total data retained for the topic.

So, you should set `log.retention.bytes` by `TARGET_DISK_SIZE/NUM_OF_TOPIC_PARTITIONS_IN_EACH_NODE`.

I think it is not intuitive, especially when the cluster has multiple topics or some possibilities to be scaled. So I personally prefer to control retention by `log.retention.hours` and use `log.retention.bytes` in the last resort.

Comment: My partitions is 3, so it still does not reclaim disk space.

Comment: @Leon Did you check your log segment size? So, when you check files in $KAFKA_LOG_DIR/$TOPIC-$partition/, there should be multiple `.log` files to rotate logs by retention.